# Cabin luggage on Australian domestic flights

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, australia

I am traveling to Australia in 2 weeks. I will be taking multiple domestic flights to go from one city to another in Australia. I found that in all of my domestic flights, I have to pay extra for check-in luggage. So, what I was thinking to do is take 2 bags with me of the following types:

1. Laptop bag.
2. Trolley bag of 55 cm (example: [here](https://www.amazon.in/American-Tourister-53W-08-001/dp/B015K2IJXC/ref=sr_1_1?s=luggage&ie=UTF8&qid=1512960962&sr=1-1&nodeID=4371862031&psd=1&keywords=AT_SoftLuggage&refinements=p_6%3AAT95IG9ONZD7S%7CA14UQ4H17XUX90)).

Is it okay to carry 2 cabin bags on domestic flights? I live in the United States and I know here it is allowed in almost all the flights. But I am not sure about Australia. I know it might depend on flights too. So, I am listed down the flights that I am using in Australia over here as follows:

1. Jetstar
2. TigerAir

Also, does someone check the weight of the bags? I know the maximum allowance is written as 7 kg for cabin luggage, but I have never seen anyone checking this. They normally just check the dimensions at most. And say, if it gets checked, what kind of fine most airlines impose and then does it go as the check-in luggage or cabin luggage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly trivial to check those two airlines websites for the cabin baggage allowances:

1. Jetstar [Cabin Baggage Allowances](http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/help/articles/carry-on-baggage-what-can-i-bring-on-board) - 1 small item (includes laptop bag) plus one main item (56cm (height) x 36cm (width) x 23cm (depth)) for a total of 7KG (more weight is included with business or higher class tickets).
2. TigerAir [Cabin Baggage Allowances](https://tigerair.com.au/prepare-to-fly/baggage#cabin-baggage) - 1 small item (examples seem smaller than a laptop bag) plus one main item (54cm (height) x 38cm (width) x 23cm (depth)) for a total of 7KG.

> Also, does someone check the weight of the bags?

That *entirely* depends on the agent checking you in or issuing your boarding card - I personally have only had my carryon weighed a few times in my travels, and then generally its been on cheaper tickets and with budget airlines.

In this case, as both airlines prominently display their charges for excess cabin baggage, and charge for checked baggage, then you will probably have your bags weighed as that is a revenue stream for them.

> what kind of fine most airlines impose

The cost of overweight hand luggage is included in the above links - Both [Jetstar](http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/help/articles/excess-baggage-charges-at-the-airport) (scroll down for cabin baggage rules) and TigerAir (on the above link) require overweight or oversize cabin baggage to be checked into the hold, which incurs a charge for both airlines.